# Contact form name string

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to have it so when the user sends the form the subject line show the user's name like "Inquiry from [Name of user]". How it's setup now it gets to me with the subject "Contact form from site." How can I modify the code to make that happen?

```
<?php
// configure
$from = 'info@mysite.com'; 
$sendTo = 'info@mysite.com';
$subject = 'Contact form at site';
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'phone' => 'Phone', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message'); // array variable name => Text to appear in email
$okMessage = 'Your Message was successfully submitted. Thank you! We will get back to you soon.';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again or call us at 970-201-9619';

// let's do the sending

try
{
    $emailText = "You have new message from your Website\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, "From: " . $from);

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information about the form (field names).

Comment: "Shows the users" like how?

Comment: Will the subject line show user's name? Like subject will 'Mail from Rahul'.

Comment: I am trying to have it so when the user sends the form the subject line displays the user's name. How it's setup now it gets to me with the subject "Contact form from site." How can I modify the code to make it so when the user submits the form their name appear in the subject line?

Comment: Yes Robert you got it right

Comment: name, surname, email, phone, message

Comment: Just like that Rahul

Answer (score 0):

Made change in the subject as per your requirement. I have moved the subject variable right above the mail sending code and concatenate name and surname of user with subject line of mail. Please check below snippet and let me know if you have any query.

```
<?php
// configure
$from = 'info@mysite.com'; 
$sendTo = 'info@mysite.com';
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'phone' => 'Phone', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message'); // array variable name => Text to appear in email
$okMessage = 'Your Message was successfully submitted. Thank you! We will get back to you soon.';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again or call us at 970-201-9619';

// let's do the sending

try
{
    $emailText = "You have new message from your Website\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }
    $subject = 'Inquiry from '.$_POST['name']." ".$_POST['surname'];
    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, "From: " . $from);

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
?>
```

Comment: @Dwayne Please accept my answer if it helped you. Welcome :)